# Can a person be muslim if he/she simply likes something about Islam?

Tags: islamic-philosophy, islamic-basis, conversion

I found a few interesting videos on youtube.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OCguMu79vg4

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WyGvjA1nGXI

In the first video, the girl converted to Islam simply because she loved Muhammad's lifestyle. She didn't say anything about "being convinced that Islam is the truth".

In the second video, another girl converted to Islam because she found the muslim community to be very helpful and fasting in ramadan helped her with her smoking addiction. But nothing that convinced her that Islam is the truth.

What do you think? Are these girls muslims? Islamic scholars are always saying that "You need to become a muslim through logic and reasoning". But in these videos, there is no mention of logic or reasoning behind believing in Islam. Rather, these girls converted to Islam simply because they liked certain things about it. Do they count as muslims?

Comment: my friend "You need to become a muslim through logic and reasoning" , you miss a lot of things . what about those kids who born in islamic family they can't be muslims until they become scientists in evolution , philosophy , islamic siences , hadith , quran , history and other relegions !? the point view of islam is clear ; islam is  a  primordial human nature ( fitrah ) ! so people could accepted anytime and sometimes without any reasons ( just knowing it is enough  ) because this is your nature ! then they get knowledge day by day !

Comment: So many scholars disagree with you unfortunately. Read this: http://www.almasjid.com/a_leap_of_faith

Comment: According to most Islamic scholars, Imaan is not accepted by Allah if it is without logic or reasoning.

Comment: Are you sure?  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalam) seems to contradict that: "Even though seeking knowledge in Islam is considered a religious obligation, the studying of 'Ilm al-Kalam is considered by Muslim scholars to fall beyond the category of necessity and is only permitted to qualified scholars, but not for the masses or common people."

Comment: I think you're asking about the wrong thing. The question isn't "how did you become convinced Islam's claims are true", the question is "are you convinced that Islam's claims are true". While you can have complete conviction about any claim without any reasonable justification whatsoever, you are unlikely to maintain that conviction when faced with evidence that undermines the claim.

Answer (score 1):

I have two points to make inshaAllah:

1 - People come to Islam in various ways.

Umar ibn Al Khattab accepted Islam after hearing the beautiful message of the Qur'an. Khalid bin Waleed accepted Islam upon the realization that Islam always triumphs and was going to triumph everywhere.  رضي الله عنهم And many others accepted Islam because they knew Prophet Muhammad صلى الله عليه وسلم  to be upright and truthful.

My point: Every person today is drawn to Islam because of some aspect of it which they liked. Some are drawn to its superior logic, clarity and reason; others are drawn to it because of its beautiful teachings on charity, kindness, etc. Some are drawn to it because of the beautiful life/character of its Messenger, Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ). The list goes on!

The two girls in the video are just telling you what drew them to Islam. And those are valid reasons which they gave too, ie sister #1 loving the Sunnah of the Messenger and sister #2 loving the compassion/brotherhood of the Muslim Ummah (which is the fruit of Islam).

Also, just because a person does not verbally tell you "I'm convinced Islam is the truth" it does not mean that they are not convinced. The fact that they accepted Islam implies that they DO accept it as the truth.. after that initial attraction to it. Unless they say otherwise, then you don't know what's in their heart.. and we always assume the best about fellow Muslims [til they give reason otherwise].

2 - Yes.. people are Muslims if they accept Islam even if they are ignorant about aspects of Islam. You're not required to know everything from the beginning (not even required to know Arabic). You're just required to know what you're saying [Shahadah] and believe in it. However, it's not *recommended* to dive into it ignorantly. People should study and get a basic understanding of Islam. And thereafter, continue to seek 'ilm (knowledge) which is an Islamic obligation.

Comment: In your answer, you said that it's not recommended to dive into Islam ignorantly. But what if one does? What if a person says shahadah without having conviction in what he's saying? Let's say a person doesn't have conviction in the oneness of Allah and the prophethood of Muhammad. But he says the shahadah simply because he feels that it MIGHT be the truth. Would Allah reject his shahadah due to his lack of conviction? Or would Allah say "I'll give him a chance. He is a muslim to me."?

Comment: Diving into Islam ignorantly doesn't negate their Islam. 

On the other hand, if there is any 'doubt' in their mind, then they haven't accepted Islam properly. True doubt is Kufr (disbelief). A Muslim has to have conviction.

Comment: What exactly is true doubt? Can doubts be dismissed as waswas? For example, let's say I'm a non-muslim. I want to convert to Islam, but I still have some doubts. But I just tell myself "This is just waswas of shaytan. I'll just ignore it". So I finally say the shahadah. Would Allah accept my Islam then?

Comment: There is a difference between doubts vs. waswasa so no, it can't be confused or dismissed. Waswasa is where you are getting thoughts in your mind that suggest evil but you hate the evil suggestions from Satan and reject them wholly [and even having them disturbs you]. Hating that and never uttering the evil is actually a sign of faith. In contrast, doubt is where you are actually confused or entertaining the idea that Islam 'could' be wrong or agreeing with evil whispers. That is disbelief. --So either you are having one or the other.

Comment: I keep having lots of doubtful thoughts about Islam. They cause me a lot of distress and anxiety. I want these thoughts to go away, but at the same time, a part of me keeps asking "What if these thoughts are right? What if I'm in the wrong religion".  I hate having these thoughts. So am I suffering from doubts or waswas?

Comment: Honestly, seems to me that you're at the point where your waswasa is about to turn into true doubt, meaning your faith could be in jeopardy IF you do not take urgent action. I just read your question about religion which I'll address eventually too inshaAllah.. but it doesn't seem to me that you've approached Islam from a very strong approach (ie, admittedly emotion only). -- You need to seek more Islamic knowledge. Satan uses your ignorance as a tool against you. So cure your ignorance by seeking knowledge.

Comment: I'm too scared to keep seeking knowledge. It's getting in the way of my life and education. Sometimes, seeking knowledge leads to more doubts and anxiety.

Comment: If you choose life/education over your eternal fate, then that's your own issue. But I've pinpointed the problem and the correct course of action to be taken. You choosing not to seek knowledge will be your own undoing. If that doesn't scare you, then you're probably already in Satan's arms.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for the great advice! I guess I'll just drop out of university and start seeking Islamic knowledge 24/7. And if I can't find anything, I'm just gonna have to hope that I don't die unexpectedly in a state of doubt. That is some great advice. My grades are going down. I'm unemployed and I already failed 3 exams this month. I might end up begging for money in the streets but that's ok. At least I was looking for answers to fix my faith. I'm sure Allah doesn't give a shit about my mental health and financial situation. Give yourself a pat on the back. Way to make my day better.

Comment: SubhanAllah. I just told you to seek it (striking a balance).. I didn't say give up everything else or to focus on it 24/7. Fear Allah (ﷻ) and stop trolling. Bye.

Comment: But what about my salah? As long as I have these doubts, will all my salah, dhikr and fasting be invalid?